# Looping through array in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ngfor

Component:

```
export class PersonalRecordsComponent implements OnInit {
  currentUser = [];
  userRecords = [];
  movements = [
    "Back Squat",
    "Bench Press",
    "Clean",
    "Clean & Jerk",
    "Custom Movement",
    "Deadlift",
    "Front Squat",
    "Jerk",
    "Power Clean",
    "Power Snatch",
    "Push Press",
    "Snatch",
    "Strict Press"
  ];

  constructor(private afService: AF) {
    // Get current user details.
    afService.getCurrentUserInfo().then(currentUserDetails => {
      this.currentUser.push(currentUserDetails);
    }).then(() => {
      for(let movement of this.movements) {
        this.afService.getRecords(movement, this.currentUser[0].userID).subscribe((data) => {
          this.userRecords.push(data);
        });
      }
    }).then(()=>{
      console.log(this.userRecords)
    })
  }
```

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let record of userRecords">
        <div class="list-athletes">
          <div class="list-athletes-details">
            <p>{{ record.movement }} - {{ record.weight }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="list-athletes-actions">
            <div class="btn-group">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
```

The above code outputs 13 `<div>`'s, which is correct but they are empty due to `*ngFor="let record of userRecords"`.  If I instead write `*ngFor="let record of userRecords[0]"` in the *ngFor loop, it outputs the correct data, but only for the first array, obviously.

My question is:  How do I output the correct data for each of the 13 arrays without writing 13 `*ngFor` loops, such as:

```
*ngFor="let record of userRecords[0]"
*ngFor="let record of userRecords[1]"
*ngFor="let record of userRecords[2]"
```

etc.

Each one of these arrays can contain multiple objects.

```
[
  [
    {
      "comments": "Back squat comment alpha",
      "movement": "Back Squat",
      "userID": "wDHZv3OL55SIymHkhMUejNleNkx1",
      "weight": "365"
    },
    {
      "comments": "Back squat comment bravo",
      "movement": "Back Squat",
      "userID": "wDHZv3OL55SIymHkhMUejNleNkx1",
      "weight": "325"
    }
  ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [
    {
      "comments": "Front squat comment alpha",
      "movement": "Front Squat",
      "userID": "wDHZv3OL55SIymHkhMUejNleNkx1",
      "weight": "315"
    }
  ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  []
]
```

Comment: show us how your userRecords array look like

Comment: @Sajeetharan added it to the post

Comment: post your array! not a screenshot! its hard

Comment: @Sajeetharan better?

Comment: just do a console.log and post the array

Comment: @Sajeetharan pasted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an idea, why not run embedded `*ngFor` loops with an `*ngIf` to ensure the array isn't empty? So you're HTML would look like...

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let lift of userRecords">
  <div *ngIf="records(lift)">
    <div *ngFor="let record of lift">
    <div class="list-athletes">
      <div class="list-athletes-details">
        <p>{{ record.movement }} - {{ record.weight }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="list-athletes-actions">
        <div class="btn-group"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

And you'd add a method to your component called `records` that would look like this:

```
public records(lifts: any[]): boolean {
   return (lifts.length > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

This function will just check to see if there are records to display.

Comment: P.S. Your front squat is pretty legit. I lose stability of the weight on my front squat so there's like always a big gap between my front squat and back squat. Do you crossfit?

Comment: I think it can just be written in template `*ngIf="lifts.length > 0"`.

Comment: It's just to skip the loop if the array is empty. Is it necessary, not at all.

Comment: @MichaelSolati thanks, it never occured to me that you could nest *ngFor loops.  Definitely fixed this issue.

Comment: @MichaelSolati and yeah I did CrossFit for two years.

Comment: The ngIf is completely unnecessary, the bested ngFor wouldnt make any iterations in case that the array is empty

Comment: @Jota.Toledo you're right, I did acknowledge that though.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest the loops:

```
<div *ngFor="let record of userRecords">
    <div *ngFor="let item of record">...
```

[Sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mw7eeUeoZSPNljYQYNUx?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two **`ngFor`** since records is also an array,

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let record of userRecords">
    <div *ngFor="let reco of record">
```

also make sure you have **`CommonModule`** imported inside the **`app.module.ts`**

Comment: dude! why you removed the answer?